# How to make desktops independent on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, application-switcher

I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 64-bit. I want to have independent desktops, so if I have app #1 on the first desktop and app #2 on the second desktop, I can't switch from app #1 to app #2 (by the word "switch" I mean pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>).

I don't know if it's necessary, but I use Ubuntu on Wayland.